# setTemplate doesn't override default layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

Default customer account page is using `page/2columns-left.phtml` and I want to override it using `page/2columns-right.phtml`.

> In my `app/design/frontend/theme/custom/layout/local.xml`, I added a new line:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="addBodyClass"><className>customer-account</className></action>
        <!-- I added below line to override "page/2columns-left.phtml"-->
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right"> <!-- I changed "left" to "right" -->
        <!-- Remove cart from the left column -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

It's a dev environment so all cache are disabled but I still flushed Magento cache but the customer account page is still using the `2columns-left` layout.
I also duplicated the `addBodyClass` line and added test class name which immediately works. `2columns-right.phtml` exists.

Comment: Maybe you have some observer who defined that template

Comment: Are there any ways to find out if it's defined in an observer? Thanks